# Plotting time series from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Trying to make a plot using Pandas with the below data frame.

```
data = {
    'date': ['2022-07-21 03:28:59.126007', '2022-07-21 03:29:01.127014', '2022-07-21 03:29:02.137008',
             '2022-07-21 03:29:05.136001', '2022-07-21 03:29:06.139007', '2022-07-21 03:53:30.094009',
             '2022-07-21 03:53:31.097000', '2022-07-21 03:53:40.096008', '2022-07-21 03:53:41.094009',
             '2022-07-21 03:53:42.094009', '2022-07-21 04:26:25.108001', '2022-07-21 04:26:26.107009',
             '2022-07-21 04:26:28.109008', '2022-07-21 04:26:29.114013', '2022-07-21 04:26:30.117004'],
    'RFID_NO': ['RFID 003', 'RFID 003', 'RFID 003', 'RFID 003',
                'RFID 003', 'RFID 002', 'RFID 002', 'RFID 002',
                'RFID 002', 'RFID 002', 'RFID 014', 'RFID 014',
                'RFID 014', 'RFID 014', 'RFID 014'],
    'RFID Location': [51, 50, 51, 50, 51, 73, 72, 73, 74, 73, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12],
    'Sh Location': [131, 132, 132, 132, 132, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data, columns=[
        'date', 'RFID_NO', 'RFID Location', 'Sh Location'])

                          date   RFID_NO  RFID Location  Sh Location
0   2022-07-21 03:28:59.126007  RFID 003             51               131
1   2022-07-21 03:29:01.127014  RFID 003             50               132
2   2022-07-21 03:29:02.137008  RFID 003             51               132
3   2022-07-21 03:29:05.136001  RFID 003             50               132
4   2022-07-21 03:29:06.139007  RFID 003             51               132
5   2022-07-21 03:53:30.094009  RFID 002             73               124
6   2022-07-21 03:53:31.097000  RFID 002             72               124
7   2022-07-21 03:53:40.096008  RFID 002             73               124
8   2022-07-21 03:53:41.094009  RFID 002             74               124
9   2022-07-21 03:53:42.094009  RFID 002             73               124
10  2022-07-21 04:26:25.108001  RFID 014              1                 6
11  2022-07-21 04:26:26.107009  RFID 014              2                 6
12  2022-07-21 04:26:28.109008  RFID 014              3                 6
13  2022-07-21 04:26:29.114013  RFID 014              4                 6
14  2022-07-21 04:26:30.117004  RFID 014             12                 6


def plot_values(df_plot):
    df_plot["date"] = df_plot["date"].astype("datetime64")
    v_RFID = df_plot['RFID Location']
    v_SLC = df_plot['Sh Location']

    df_plot = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(v_RFID, v_SLC)),
                           index=df_plot["date"],
                           columns=['RFID_no', 'Sh Location'])
    df_plot.plot()
    plt.show()

plot_values(df)
```

[image]

As seen in the frame, there are 3 RFID's, (003, 002, 014). How do I plot each RFID number, its location v time separately and display in a legend? The RFID location (blue) has the three combined. Do I 'somehow' need to split the RFID_no column out into separate columns and related values?

Tks

Comment: The easiest way is to use seaborn, which requires converting the dataframe from wide to long form with `.melt`: `dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['date', 'RFID_NO'], var_name='Location', value_name='Value')`, and then plot `g = sns.relplot(data=dfm, kind='line', x='date', y='Value', col='Location', hue='RFID_NO', marker='o')`. You can switch the `hue=` and the `col=` value. [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuqEp.png)

Comment: If you want them all on one plot, the use `style=` instead of `col=`: `g = sns.relplot(data=dfm, kind='line', x='date', y='Value', style='Location', hue='RFID_NO', marker='o')`. [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf4kw.png)

Comment: Depending on the number of observations, you may want `'sharex': False`: `g = sns.relplot(data=dfm, kind='line', x='date', y='Value', hue='Location', col='RFID_NO', marker='o', facet_kws={'sharey': True, 'sharex': False})` [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIypp.png)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney exactly what I am after. tks. An now I understand where hue = 'RFID_NO' fits (BeRT2me)

Answer (score 0):

You use date as the x-coordinate, but they don't have a uniform date value after the RFID_NO distinction, so obviously they can't be placed in one diagram,you could try using subdiagrams to achieve this.

If you need to add other attributes you can change them yourself

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'RFID_NO', 'RFID Location', 'Sh Location'])


for i, (RFID, item) in enumerate(df.groupby("RFID_NO")):
    plt.subplot(3, 1, i+1)
    item["date"] = pd.to_datetime(item["date"])
    plt.plot(item["date"], item["Sh Location"], label=RFID)
    plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: You didn't separate the data by location though

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

```
# Prepare "date" column as index
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df = df.set_index("date")

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1)
for ax, (name, data) in zip(axes, df.groupby("RFID_NO")):
    data.plot(ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(name)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]